# getting error while doing cat command "Ambiguous output redirect."

Tags: command-line, unix, redirection, csh

while executing

```
cat test.txt | java myfile > test1.txt 2> test2.txt
```

I am getting error "Ambiguous output redirect."

my java file contains System.out and System.err .

I am in Unix csh environment.

Comment: can you be more specific than "unix csh"?  are you using *tcsh*?  on Linux? BSD? Solaris? AIX?  HPUX?  (oh gawd, tell me you're not on HPUX... please... i still have nightmares)

Comment: i am using tcsh .

Comment: I am sad for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it 
in unix tcsh env i can run as follows :

```
(cat test.txt | java myfile > test1.txt) >& test2.txt
```